# Optimal query for replacing multiple chars at once?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace a number of different chars in a large table. As these are from the Windows-1252 charset, I refer to the chars by ascii code. These can be found in several columns. The naive approach is to either replace each of these individually or nest the replacement.

Individual replacement:

```
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, CHR(147), '"'), city = REPLACE(city, CHR(147), '"');
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, CHR(148), '"'), city = REPLACE(city, CHR(148), '"');
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, CHR(150), '-'), city = REPLACE(city, CHR(150), '-');
....
```

Nesting, as described here: http://oraclecoder.com/tutorials/oracle-multiple-replace-function--2989.

I'm curious if one is better than the other. Or if there's a third option that is even better? I have a great number of rows to iterate over, so anything that will improve performance is really appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`TRANSLATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) function to do it at once:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT  '“”–' AS name
  FROM dual
)
SELECT name, TRANSLATE(name, '“”–', '""-') AS result
FROM cte;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/13498/0)**</kbd>

In your case:

```
UPDATE table 
SET name = TRANSLATE(name, '“”–', '""-'),
    city = TRANSLATE(name, '“”–', '""-')
-- WHERE REGEX_LIKE(name, '.*(“|”|–).*')    -- filter record for update
--    OR REGEX_LIKE(city, '.*(“|”|–).*')
```

From [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252):

```
147 - “    Left  double curved quote
148 - ”    Right double curved quote
150 - –    En dash
```